# Is My Android App In Review?

Tags: android, marketplace

Last night, I submitted my Android App to the Android Marketplace. I clicked publish and currently it has a green check mark saying published...

I don't have any downloads, so I'm wondering if it has to be reviewed or something...

My app is called Rubik's Cube Secrets.

If it is published how do I get people to actually download it?

Also is there any code that is needed to add. Don't you have to do something with debug = true?

Comment: At least it is not in review. Apple does that.

Comment: Have you actually tried installing it from the Market yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is published It would say published with a green tick. There is no review process in android market.

You could try a press release, admob etc to spread news about your app.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any downloads, so I'm wondering if it has to be reviewed or something...

Nope. [It's published](https://market.android.com/details?id=cloud.apps.rubik.cheats&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNsb3VkLmFwcHMucnViaWsuY2hlYXRzIl0.) just waiting for downloads.

> If it is published how do I get people to actually download it?

Well, there are entire books / blog series on that subject. Some ideas:

1. Make a free "lite" version of the app to promote the paid one.
2. Pay a 3rd party to market the app for you (such as [these guys](http://www.appbrain.com/info/advertise) (I have no experience with them)).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is your app? https://market.android.com/details?id=cloud.apps.rubik.cheats&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNsb3VkLmFwcHMucnViaWsuY2hlYXRzIl0.

In case it is, it is published. Generally, Android applications are published at the very second you press "publish". It does take some time for Google to update the search cache, but if you know the URL you will be able to see it in the market.

Getting people to download it is the hard part. You can pay Google to advertise it, which may or may not be an alternative. Another possibility is having your friends download it and spread the word. In the end, there is no general answer to how you can get people to download it, as it depends on if you are willing to pay for adverticement or not.